# Converting Unix timestamp to wordpress date

Tags: date, date-time, timestamp

I have trouble converting Unix timestamp (i.e. 1473897600) to Wordpress friendly date which displays at the date input field. I have a frontpage, post edit panel which is showing Unix timestamp.

I guess this is the code for getting the post's date;

```
<?php   $post_to_edit = array();
        $post_to_edit = get_post($_POST['postid']); 

        $date = $_POST[ '_single_date' ];   ?>
```

And editing and updating the date with following code works fine;

```
update_post_meta($pid, '_single_date', strtotime($date) );
```

date input field;

```
<input value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_to_edit->ID, '_single_date', true); ?>" name="_single_date" />
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use [date_i18n()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/):

```
$timestamp = get_post_meta($post_to_edit->ID, '_single_date', true);

$friendly_date = date_i18n( get_option('date_format'), $timestamp );

?><input value="<?= $friendly_date ?>" name="_single_date" />
```